# Getting value of spinbox and printing it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to print the value of the box variable. Could someone please help?
I'm trying to create a dice roller (mostly just for fun) and I can't work out what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
dice.set(1)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python


def ShowChoice():
    print(dice.get())


labelchoose = Label(main, text="""Choose your dice:""").place(x=5, y=5)


dice4choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D4", variable=dice, value=1).place(x=5, y=25)
dice6choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D6", variable=dice, value=2).place(x=5, y=45)
dice8choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D8", variable=dice, value=3).place(x=5, y=65)
dice10choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D10", variable=dice, value=4).place(x=5, y=85)
dice12choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D12", variable=dice, value=5).place(x=5, y=105)
dice20choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D20", variable=dice, value=6).place(x=5, y=125)
dicepercentilechoice = Radiobutton(main, text="Percentile", variable=dice, value=7).place(x=5, y=145)


boxlabel = Label(main, text="How many times are you rolling?").place(x=175, y=5)
box = Spinbox(main, to=20).place(x=175, y=25)


def rolldice():
    if dice4choice == 1:
        print box()


rollbutton = Button(main, text="Roll!", command=rolldice).place(x=5, y=175)
```

Comment: you can do ```item_1=IntVar()``` then ```box = Spinbox(main,textvariable=item_1, to=20).place(x=175, y=25)``` and then in ```def rolldice()```, you can update ```print box()``` to ```print (item_1.get())```

Comment: For a more simpler code, you can update ```print box()``` to ```print(box.get())```

Answer (score 0):

Here, just call `.get()`

```
def rolldice():
    if dice4choice == 1:
        print(box.get())
```

Or you can just do the following. The `textvariable` parameter allows you to set a variable. It will assign the value on the `spinbox` to it which will give the value when you invoke the `.get()`

```
dice.set(1)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python


def ShowChoice():
    print(dice.get())

item_1=IntVar() #=== Intvar is defined
labelchoose = Label(main, text="""Choose your dice:""").place(x=5, y=5)


dice4choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D4", variable=dice, value=1).place(x=5, y=25)
dice6choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D6", variable=dice, value=2).place(x=5, y=45)
dice8choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D8", variable=dice, value=3).place(x=5, y=65)
dice10choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D10", variable=dice, value=4).place(x=5, y=85)
dice12choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D12", variable=dice, value=5).place(x=5, y=105)
dice20choice = Radiobutton(main, text="D20", variable=dice, value=6).place(x=5, y=125)
dicepercentilechoice = Radiobutton(main, text="Percentile", variable=dice, value=7).place(x=5, y=145)


boxlabel = Label(main, text="How many times are you rolling?").place(x=175, y=5)
box = Spinbox(main,textvariable=item_1, to=20).place(x=175, y=25)


def rolldice():
    if dice4choice == 1:
        print(item_1.get())


rollbutton = Button(main, text="Roll!", command=rolldice).place(x=5, y=175)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **tkinter** if you assign a widget to a variable in this way:

```
btn = Button().pack()
```

you lose control of that widget because the method `.pack()` returns `None`.

**Correct way**

```
btn = Button()
btn.pack()
```

Here i wrote a simple example to print the value of a **Spinbox** using the method `.get()`:

```
from tkinter import *


class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()

        self.title("Spinbox")
        self.geometry("300x200")

        self.box = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=100)
        self.box.pack(pady=25)

        self.btn_show_value = Button(self, text="PRINT VALUE", command=lambda: print(self.box.get()))
        self.btn_show_value.pack(pady=15)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wouldnt recommend using `lambda` or a *Class*  in a answer for a beginner that dosent know how these things work.

Comment: **tkinter** is based entirely on classes and class inheritance, and `lambda` functions are widely used in tkinter tutorials for such operations. I take it for granted that if you use a module based on the classes you also know the balisilar principles of the functioning of the classes, mine does not want to be a ready-to-use answer but a starting point to deepen.